# Re-mapped Caps key not working properly with `x`

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have remapped my Caps Lock to Control key.

Now there is one specific case in which the key doesn't work properly. When I press new `Control` key (the Caps key acually) and `x` key together, it just ignores the `x` key. I tested it using the program `xev` and I was able to confirm this behavior. In fact this only happens with the `x` key. Other keys work fine with this combination. The other control keys (the actual control keys) works fine with the `x` key. Any idea why this is happening ?

Ubuntu version: 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: OS is fine, Hardware's fault.

I tried the same operating system in one of my other laptop and the remapped key worked fine there. After more fiddling, I noticed that my `Ctrl-w`, `Ctrl-s` was also not working. After a bit of search, I came across this [thread in freedesktop bugzilla](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1322#c6) where another user had the same problem like me. So, finally this turned out to be a limitation of the keyboard hardware. (My laptop is Dell Vostro 3559 - Buyers beware :-)). As of now, I'm using an external keyboard which works fine with my re-mapped Caps key.